# Controlling the number of significant digits used by jsonencode

Tags: matlab, significant-digits, jsonencode

I'd like to use [jsonencode](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html?searchHighlight=jsonencode&s_tid=srchtitle_jsonencode_1) in Matlab R2022a to encode a structure containing double precision values, like e.g.:

```
>> s = struct('a', sqrt(2))
s = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 1.4142

>> jsonencode(s)
ans =
    '{"a":1.4142135623730951}'
```

But I don't need all the digits and I'd like to keep the JSON file short, so I'd like to have an output like:

```
'{"a":1.414}'
```

There does not seem to have such an option in `jsonencode`, so I have tried to remove the less significant digits beforehand. Unfortunately there are random rounding errors:

```
>> s.a = round(s.a*10^3)*10^-3
s = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 1.4140

>> jsonencode(s)
ans = 
'{"a":1.4140000000000005}'
```

These errors do not occur all the time, but it seems that the deeper the `struct` the more often I have these rounding errors.

Then I have tried to use [vpa](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), but it does not seem to be compatible with `jsonencode`:

```
>> s.a = vpa(s.a,4)
s = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 1.414

>> jsonencode(s)
ans =
    '{"a":{}}'
```

Now I'm out of options. Is it possible to get a clean JSON output with control over the significant digits using pure Matlab ?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way I round numbers by using a feature of the `round` function  and it removed the random rounding approximations (probably due to the division by the power of 10):

```
>> s.a = round(s.a, 4, 'significant')
s = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 1.414

>> jsonencode(s)
ans = 
    '{"a":1.414}'
```